# post data in form is not read on action page if click in address bar and press enter

Tags: html, forms, jsp, web

I have a form which uses post method to post the data. On the action page, i receive the data. 
If i refresh the page , it ask that Information you have to enter again(in chrome) and if I click on continue it gets the same post data and works properly. However if on the same action  page, I click on address bar and press enter, data is lost.

How can I handle that?

Answer (score 0):

you can't.
hitting enter in the address bar will result in a GET request.
when you refresh the page the browser will resend your last request that's why it asks if you are sure to POST again.